# Melhorar as rotas

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, rotas

Gente tem alguma forma melhor de fazer estas rotas? Ou para cada action no meu Controller vou ter que criar seu roteamento?

```
app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
               "Login",
               "Login",
               new { controller = "Usuario", action = "Login" }
               );
            routes.MapRoute(
               "registro",
               "Registro",
               new { controller = "Usuario", action = "Registro" }
               );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ao criar um projeto ASP.NET Core MVC, você terá como padrão a seguinte rota:

```
app.UseMvc(routes =>
{
   routes.MapRoute("default", "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
});
```

Basicamente, ela interpreta da seguinte forma:

- 1º Token: **Controler**: se não for informado, utilizar o controller **Home**;
- 2º Token: **Action**: se não for informado, utilizar o método **Index**;
- 3º Token: **ID**: se não for informado, não será enviado (é opcional). E somente será enviado caso o método informado, no 2º token, possua algum parâmetro que se chame "id";

Esse modelo de rota, pode suprir a grande maioria das rotas do seu site. Você ainda pode expandir ou adicionar novas rotas genéricas.

Se todas as suas rotas são similares, você pode criar apenas uma utilizando *tokens* (*tokenizing*) os valores que podem ser passados na Rota.

Analisando a rota default, as seguintes rotas serão supridas:

> /Products/Details/5

Interpretada da seguinte forma:

```
{ controller = Products, action = Details, id = 5 }
```

Ou apenas

> /Products

Interpretada da seguinte forma:

```
{ controller = Products, action = Index}
```

Mais informações você pode encontrar no manual [Routing to controller actions in ASP.NET Core](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing?view=aspnetcore-2.1)

Comment: Mais uma duvida, mudei para o esquema de "Attribute routing", acha isso uma boa ou não recomenda fazer as rotas dessa forma?https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing?view=aspnetcore-2.1#attribute-routing

Comment: Attribute routing permite deixar a rota junto do método que será utilizado e também permite uma precisão maior. O uso é totalmente válido. O importante é manter tudo limpo e conciso.